# session_start(): Session data file is not created by your uid

Tags: php, session

I want to store the created sessions in a directory above the root, except when I use any of the following:

```
    session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../storage/sessions');
    session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../storage/sessions/'); // With an extra slash at the end
ini_set('session.save_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../storage/sessions');
ini_set('session.save_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../storage/sessions/'); // Again with the extra slash
```

and not one of these methods work, whenever I load the page I get the following errors:

> Warning: session_start(): Session data file is not created by your uid
>   in /var/www/bootstrap/bootstrap.php on line 25
>
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path:
>   /var/www/public/../storage/sessions/) in
>   /var/www/bootstrap/bootstrap.php on line 25

Can anyone help me?

**Edit:** My server runs on PHP 7.1

Comment: It's a linux user permissions error; make sure your able to read/write to those locations(folders should be 0755 and your files should be 0644), and that your user has permission to read to those locations.

Comment: how can I find out which user wants to access those locations? and changing permissions is chown right?

Comment: I have tried all of the above solutions, change the folders folder, create another folder for the session, manage a session by redis, and nothing worked, which solved my problem leaving session.auto_start = 1 which means enabled, in php.ini

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP requires session file to be owned by the user running PHP.

Then just run `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/storage/sessions/` to own session folder and files by your PHP user (`www-data:www-data` are your PHP user and group separated by `:`).

You can use PHP method `get_current_user()` or run in bash `php -i | grep user` and find your user running PHP there.

Comment: in my case `/var/www/storage/sessions/` directory doesn't exist
neither `/usr/local/var/www/storage/sessions/` directory exists.
and yes i am in mac.

also after creating the mentioned directory and trying to change ownership or the directory it shows `chown: www-data: illegal group name`

Comment: Also it used to work before i restarted my mac and now it stopped working

Answer (score 5):

this works for me:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but please read the question carefully: OP wants to use a custom session save_path. Your answer might work with the default settings but is unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Editing **config/config.yml** and replacing save_path:

```
session:
    save_path: '/tmp'
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu within Windows 10 , my php user is the default user I create for the first install, I dont know why because the `etc/apache2/envvars` is not configured like that.

Nevermind, I change it for fix it quickly and now, it works.

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=rudak
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=rudak
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me, could work for you as well.

It looks like something went wrong with the session. Open the browser's DevTools and delete all Sessioncookies.

Answer (score 1):

I could be that your Session file was created by another user (well UID), try (re)moving the session file(s) from your temp dir something like /var/tmp

Answer (score 1):

I use this to also make **Named Pipes** in php.

```
<?php
$user = get_current_user();   // get current process user

// We need to modify the permissions so users can write to it

exec( "chown -R {$user}:{$user} $fifoPath" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: rename your session folder
var/session to var/session_old

create a new folder
var/session

and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

For **lampp** users,
- go to /opt/lampp/temp/ 
- delete session file, and test again

After testing again, 
If error message **"Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!"** shows, 
 Run the following at terminal: 
`sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

That worked for me ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have xampp with M1 ARM based please follow the below steps if you have the same

1. First find **session.save_path** from
   **http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php**
2. Then remove all existing
   sessions

I followed the above & it worked

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was just to wipe the contents of the sessions folder. Not sure how or why that helped, but it did.