# SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid

Tags: php, session, magento, magento-1.9, magento2

I tried to install Magento and I had this error:

```
[ERROR] Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid in /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22 in /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/var/www/drupal...', 22, Array)
#1 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php(22): SessionHandler->read('13b49b9426776de...')
#2 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(93): Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Native->read('13b49b9426776de...')
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->read('13b49b9426776de...')
#4 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(189): session_start()
#5 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(167): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#6 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->start()
#7 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(100): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State))
#8 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State), Object(Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy), Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Url), Object(Magento\Backend\App\Config))
#9 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State), Object(Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy), Object(Magento\Backend\Model\Url), Object(Magento\Backend\App\Config))
#10 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Backend...', Array)
#11 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')
#12 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')
#13 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'authSession', 'Magento\\ImportE...')
#14 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\ImportE...', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\ImportE...', Array, Array)
#16 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\ImportE...')
#17 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\ImportE...')
#18 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\ImportE...', NULL, 'importHistoryMo...', 'Magento\\ImportE...')
#19 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\ImportE...', Array, Array)
#20 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\ImportE...', Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\ImportE...')
#22 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\ImportE...')
#23 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\ImportE...', NULL, 'importModel', 'Magento\\Configu...')
#24 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array)
#25 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Configu...')
#27 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Configu...')
#28 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Configu...', NULL, 'configurablePro...', 'Magento\\Configu...')
#29 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array)
#30 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array)
#31 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Configu...')
#32 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Configu...')
#33 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Configu...', NULL, 'installer', 'Magento\\Configu...')
#34 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array)
#36 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Configu...', Array)
#37 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(946): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Configu...')
#38 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1250): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createSchemaDataHandler('Magento\\Configu...', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#39 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(856): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->getSchemaDataHandler('Magento_Configu...', 'data-install')
#40 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(783): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data')
#41 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
#42 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(334): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#43 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#44 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#45 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#46 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#47 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#49 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#50 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#51 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#52 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#53 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#54 /var/www/drupalvm/magento/magentotest/setup/index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#55 {main}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session\_start(): Session data file is not created by your uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771425/session-start-session-data-file-is-not-created-by-your-uid)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the ownership of the project directory to the user that you want to be the main user of the project.

```
sudo chown -R myuser: ./src
```