# PHP Session data file is not created by your uid (Vagrant CentOS)

Tags: php, session, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I try to do the following:

`ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/www/example/sessions');`

`session_start();`

but I get the following error:

> session_start(): Session data file is not created by your uid

I check `get_current_user()` in returns `vagrant`

I check permission of `/var/www/example/sessions` it returns:

`drwxrwxrwx  1 vagrant vagrant 4.0K Dec 11 01:58 sessions`

---

Note: the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771425/session-start-session-data-file-is-not-created-by-your-uid/42062526) does not work for me because doing:

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example/sessions/` returns an error:

`chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’`.

In Vagrant, it appears `vagrant` is the PHP user.

---

Note: The session files appears to get created inside the custom session folder but they are empty. e.g., `sess_k92fdn46onm5an0mau6p50tr2g` doesn't contain anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check the file permission for the sessions folder?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Yup `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Same issue for me on a ubuntu machine. The php user is vagrant and the file owner is vagrant, but there are only empty session files created. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, your user is `vagrant`. Have you tried running `sudo chown -R www-data:vagrant /var/www/example/sessions/`? You are getting the error because `www-data` is not a user. Hope this helps.

Comment: Same error: `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:vagrant’`

Comment: Apologies! Totally didn't see that you were on CentOS. In a Cent environment data should be owned by `apache` to be able to modify them.

Comment: You mean to say there's no solution to this because `vagrant` is the owner?

Comment: Not too familiar with Cent but I believe the command I recommended should work if you swap `vagrant` for `apache`

Comment: Both `www-data:apache` and `apache:apache` returns `chown: invalid user`

Comment: Have you created the `www-data` user? Try `grep www-data /etc/passwd` to see if it exists.

Comment: I created the user `www-data` but `chown` doesn't do anything. The dir is still owned by `vagrant`.

Comment: I managed to change the folder group/owner to `www-data` via [vagrant config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706318/748789) however I still get the same error `session_start(): Session data file is not created by your uid`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185082/discussion-between-kevin-and-imb).